# Semantic React UI Pop Up not working when given an ID

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

Hello just a random technical question I'm currently working on a react project using the semantic-react-ui framework. I'm using the popup component to show additional information in a form group. My question is why does providing an ID to the field that's supposed to trigger the popup prevent it from working? Thanks!